# Scheduled run 'Run stopped by user'

Tags: hp-uft, uft14

Has anyone run into the problem where you schedule a suite of test to run in ALM, they run on a remote machine and when you look at the run report you see "Not Completed" and the reason the script stopped was it says "Run stopped by user." when in fact you didn't stop the run.

I use ALM to schedule suites of our UFT tests that are contained in test suites.  I schedule them to run on the weekend when no one is in the office.  I've given the suite longer to run than it takes and even put buffer space in between timeslots.

The scripts will run through from start to finish if you are logged in watching them, or if you kicked off the suite manually.  But over the weekend when you have them scheduled I keep getting so many that are not completed, which causes the rest of the scripts in the suite to go 'No Run'. The reason the not completed ones stopped, 'Run stopped by user', but there is no user invention, no one has stopped the run, ALM/UFT does it for some reason.  Please help!

*Screenshot:*
[image: This is what the report looks like]

Comment: Given the runtime at about 3am, is it possible that your IT Support department has a scheduled reboot/patch window/update service at the point your scripts are executing?

Comment: The run time is actually over the day.  So 20 suites will be scheduled to start the run at 12am and the last one will be scheduled at 1pm.  But I just confirmed that the time and day don't play a factor.  I scheduled the same run in the same format for today during the day and got the same results